# Facebook Posting using FB API phpSDK

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

i created my app on fb with permissions ready to publish on users behalf, the thing is, a regular post has Like and Comment links, like buttons on bottom of the post, i want to add my custom link : VOTE NOW, its a poll post

how can i do that?

someone gave an answer but for js sdk not php, n i cant find it on facebook dev documentation

some gave a close enough solution, but ddnt seem to work on php with modifications

```
FB.ui({
    method: "feed",
    link: "LINK_URL",
   ...
   actions: [
        { name: "Read Now", link: "URL TO THE READ NOW " }
   ]
}, function(response) { console.log(response); });
```

> > It seems it's working with /me/feed  but with my custom /me/xxxxxx:submitted_a_poll/  its not working

Answer (score 0):

When you make a call with the PHP SDK, you also pass a similar set of parameters:

```
$attachment = array(
  'link' => 'http://your-cool-site.com',
  'description' => 'This is the description',
  ...
  'actions' => array(
     array(
       'name' => 'Vote Now!',
       'link' => 'http://your-cool-site.com/vote.php'
     )
  )
);
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
```

All you really have to do is add the relevant `action` settings to your parameters.

Comment: it worked as /me/feed/ but with /me/stunpoll:submitted_a_poll its not working, any idea?